# Why isn't my drop down value being submitted to the action?

Tags: c#, razor

I have a DropDownListFor on my view. In fact I have 3, out of three of them only two of them work. Despite being almost exactly the same code, my get around at the moment is to create an input box and populate it on click of a button with the value from the drop down box(strange I know, I can get the value using JQuery). I've checked and all names seem to be the same so I'm really not sure why it doesn't submit.

View:

```
<content id="GenerateReportContent" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ReportSelection", "Search", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "GenerateReportContainer" })) {

        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="AltFunctions">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('GenerateReportContainer').reset();" class="AltButton" id="altClearButton" title="Reset the 'Generate Report' container" >Clear</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#GRModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#GRModal" class="AltButton" id="GRaltInfoButton" title="Information on the 'Generate Report' container">Info</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <h1 id="GenerateReportHeader">SEARCH ENGINE</h1>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="ClientID" value="@Model.ClientID" id="Client" />
        <input type="hidden" name="ClientName" value="@Model.ClientName" id="ClientName" />
        <input type="hidden" name="SupplierFound" value="@Model.SupplierFound" id="SupplierFound" />

        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ClaimNo, "", new { @id = "txtGRCSelect", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter Specific Claim Number..." }) 
        <br />

        <div class="ui-widget">
            @Html.TextBox("SupplierAuto", "", new { @id = "SupplierAutotxt", @class = "form-control SupplierAutoComplete", placeholder = "Search for a supplier name" })
        </div>

        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SupplierID, new SelectList(Model.Suppliers, "SupplierID", "DisplayName"), "Select Supplier Name", new { @id = "SuppNameDD", @class = "GRDropDown"})

        <br />

        <!-- THE DROP DOWN IN QUESTION-->
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GroupModelClass.GroupID, new SelectList(Model.GroupModelClass.ClaimGroups, "GroupID", "GroupName"), "Select Supplier Group Name", new { @id = "SuppGroupDD", @class = "GRDropDown" })

        <br />

        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ReviewPeriodID, new SelectList(Model.ReviewPeriods, "ReviewPeriodID", "ReviewPeriodName"), "Select Review Period", new { @id = "ReviewPeriodDD", @class = "GRDropDown" })

        // Have to submit this field at the moment as the drop down value is not being submitted
        <input hidden id="GroupIDInput" name="GroupIDInput" />

        <br />
        <br />
        <button type="submit" value="Submit" id="GenerateReportButton" class="btn btn-default">GO</button>

        <div id="ErrorBox" hidden>
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
                <p id="ErrorBoxText"></p>
            </div>
        </div>

    }

</content>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ReportSelection(int ClientID, string ClaimNo, string SupplierAuto, int? SupplierID = null, int? ReviewPeriodID = null, int? GroupID = null) {

            if (SupplierAuto != "") {
                var Suppliers = suppRepo.GetAllSuppliersByClientWithClaims(ClientID);
                foreach (var item in Suppliers) {
                    if (item.DisplayName == SupplierAuto) {
                        SupplierID = item.SupplierID;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (SupplierID == null) {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard", new { ClientID = ClientID });
                }
            }

            client = clientRepo.GetClientNameByID(ClientID);


            if (SupplierID != null || ReviewPeriodID != null || GroupIDInput != null) {
                return RedirectToAction("SupplierReportSelection", new { ClientID = ClientID, SupplierID = SupplierID, ReviewPeriodID = ReviewPeriodID, ClaimIDs = ClaimIDs });
            }
            else {
                return RedirectToAction("ClaimNumberReportSelection", new { ClientID = ClientID, ClaimNo = ClaimNo });
            }

        }
```

Anyone know why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Use FormCollection:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShowAllMobileDetails(MobileViewModel MV,FormCollection form)
{           
  string strDDLValue = form["<your-dropdown-name>"].ToString();

  return View(MV);
}
```

If you want with Model binding then add a property in Model:

```
public class MobileViewModel 
{          
    public List<tbInsertMobile> MobileList;
    public SelectList Vendor { get; set; }
    public string SelectedVender {get;set;}
}
```

and in View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SelectedVender , Model.Vendor, "Select Manufacurer")
```

and in Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShowAllMobileDetails(MobileViewModel MV)
{           
   string SelectedValue = MV.SelectedVendor;
   return View(MV);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with fiddler or F12, but I'm betting m.GroupModelClass.GroupID is getting passed to the model binder as simply GroupID and it has no idea that it's supposed to map to GroupModelClass.GroupID.  Try flattening your model a bit?